ORA-01843 not valid month
I’m trying to run a script PL\SQL Developer. Script is below and getting error ORA-01843 not valid month.
Select * from rawtable 
Where reportdatetime between ‘21/01/2000 08:00:00’ AND ‘18/03/2024 08:00:00’

The repordatetime format from rawtable is DD/MM/YYYY
I have tried changing format but not working

Use TO_DATE to enforce the intended date format you want to search, for example: https://dbfiddle.uk/JDc0kTRL

You can also write date literals in Oracle as date'yyyy-mm-dd'
